# Dockerfile => failed to solve: circular dependency detected on stage

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a symfony app within php-fpm-alpine docker container. I want to deploy as it is so I need an Nginx container, this is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.21.6-alpine

ADD ./docker/nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
ADD ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

FROM ikerib/aurki2de:latest as aurkibide
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY --from=aurkibide /usr/src/app/public .
```

but the result is

```
[nginx internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                       
 => => transferring context: 255B                                                                                                                                                                             
 => [nginx internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                   
 => => transferring dockerfile: 320B                                                                                                                                                                          
failed to solve: circular dependency detected on stage: aurkibide
make: *** [Makefile:27: run] Error 17
```

Why? How can I check where is the circular reference? How to debug ?

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to achive with this line `COPY --from=aurkibide /usr/src/app/public .`?

Comment: serve the assets that are builded on the aurkibide container https://pastebin.com/UF1X6V6u . If I use a docker compose with php-fpm and a different one with nginx, from nginx can't read inside docker public folder https://pastebin.com/TFCGuTLD

Comment: Your last stage starts `FROM` that image, so you're trying to `COPY` the files from the image to itself.  The error is saying that the `... AS aurkibide` is trying to `COPY --from=aurkibide`, and it can't build that stage before itself to copy the files in.  Do you actually need that `COPY` line at all?

Comment: you are right I changed the order and now works! thx!